# What is this abbreviation symbol in War of 1812 Pension File?

Tags: palaeography, pension-records, war-of-1812

This [image from Fold](https://www.fold3.com/image/314142383) has a symbol that I cannot identify, shown circled here:

[image]

My transcription reads:

> Allowed July 23' 1860 at the rate of $4.00 per month from Febry 1<sup>st</sup> 1859, Subject to all pay ments made on Certificate No 1137 issued April 11<sup>th</sup> 1859 ?-$3 50/100 per month. Janison

What is the symbol and what does it mean?

Based on the full record, including prior images in the file, it relates to the prior pension amount being $3.50 which is here being raised to $4.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the word is "at", with the cross of the "t" displaced (as is the case with the last "t" in the word "certificate" in the line above".

Also, I think  it may be "52/100", rather than "50/100"

So my transcription of that last line would be:

> "... 1859 at $3 52/100 per month. Janison"

However,  note that there is a displaced bar on the "5" in the "1859" and that the second "0" in "100" isn't closed, so reading that as "50/100" is perfectly plausible.

Comparing the handwriting with more examples from this file, or with other documents written by the same person, will give greater confidence in one reading or the other.

Comment: I know from other images that it is $3.50, not $3.52.

Comment: @WilliamKF Fair enough.  That's the advantage of having more source data. :)

Comment: I think it's 3.50; the thing that you're seeing as the top bar of the 2 is the displaced top bar of the 5.

Comment: @shoover Yes. I noticed there's also a displaced bar on the "5" in the "1859" (as well as the fact that the second "0" in "100" isn't closed).  With such a small snippet it's always going to be hard to draw definitive conclusions which is why I said "I think it may be "52/100" ...", rather than "I think it is ...".    I'll edit my answer to make that explicit.